# How to design system around state of object to not duplicate mechanisms in code and back-end?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, architecture, state

System I am working with ATM is C# and oracle however problem I am having is system agnostic (could happen to system with java and mysql or any other front-end and back-end combination):

I have `TransactionDetail` object that can have 9 statuses

```
Open, 
Complete, 
Cancelled,
No Quote, 
Quoted, 
Instructed, 
Declined, 
Refunded, 
Removed
```

From my experience when one has to deal with statuses in front-end code he should do everything he can to avoid object status having a setter. It is because status is inherent quality and has to be determined at the moment when it is being needed - in other words status should always be determined by a method or get only property and not set.

So statuses are being retrieved with mechanisms like this (this is only a fragment of code but should give you indication how it works)

```
public TransactionStatus TransactionStatus()
{
    if (db.DeclinedTransactions.Any(o => o.TransactionId == this.TransactionId))
        return TransactionStatus.Declined;
}
```

MI is asking for these transaction statuses in a SQL view that would also contain all the data related to transaction.

If object status can be determined only from data of object itself creating computed columns can solve this problem in database. But what about objects like `TransactionDetail` that spans multiple tables - there isn't computed column mechanism that would allow to 'peek' into other tables.

The only solution I can think of is adding SQL function that determines state and then create a SQL view that contains function + data from table. What I don't like about this approach is that it requires to duplicate logic in code and in database.

**How one should design system around state of object which to be determined requires information from more than one table, in a way that would not require to duplicate mechanisms in code and back-end?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were a project I was working on, I would not be looking to create a View to calculate this data.

I would be looking at my application business logic.

Whilst a fully normalised database makes perfect sense to the DBAs, there are cases where application performance and scalability can benefit greatly from a little de-normalization.

If you have a reliable framework of business logic (i.e. well defined business objects, good encapsulation, reliable unit tests) then I would personally be looking to add this to the business objects.

This then allows you to define you Status behaviour in code and update an explicit Status.  For example, if a change is made to a business object that puts it into a different `TransactionStatus` then you can explicitly make the change to that status on the business object and persist the entire change to your database.

The usual response to this kind of design suggestion is that you then have to ensure you have the burden of keeping the two things in sync (explicit status vs state of the object) - the answer to that is making sure there is only one piece of logic to carry out these changes and that your business logic is water-tight as described before.

An example:

- Invoice contains one or more InvoiceItem
- InvoiceItem has a value.
- Invoice, when displayed, needs an invoice value total

Usual way that this is done is to use `SUM()` to calculate the Invoice total "on the fly" in the database to populate an Invoice.Total value.

But if my business logic is well defined - perhaps I add InvoiceItem to an Invoice object in code, and the `Add` logic also takes the value from InvoiceItem and adds it to an `Invoice.Total` value -  then when I commit the changes, I can also commit that Invoice.Total value.

When I want to display the total, I have a single value, rather than having to aggregate in the database.